# Python PIL deteriorates image when converting to RGBA

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgba

I am processing images with PIL. When I open and convert some images to RGBA they get completely deteriorated.

One example of such an image is the following one:

[image: Input image]

```
$ file input_image.png
input_image.png: PNG image data, 502 x 1180, 16-bit grayscale, non-interlaced
```

After the conversion I get the following:

[image: Output image]

I run the following code.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("input_image.png")
img_rgba = img.convert("RGBA")
img_rgba.save("output_image.png")
```

I would expect that the output image looks like the input image.

Comment: Could you try to do `img.convert("RGBA").quantize()` ?

Comment: Writing an application where I work, I was having to convert images to PNG and JPG for consumption in PySimpleGUI (tk, only supported png at the time) and MS Word. I had to rewrite the image processing in rust to get the test batch from over eight hours to under three minutes. There might be a hack you can do for the image conversion just by swapping columns around.

Comment: `img.convert("RGBA").quantize()` didn't make any difference

Comment: If you save `img` (without conversion), do you get back the original image, or is it strange already? What happens if you try `RGBa` instead of `RGBA`? Btw, are you sure about that you need an alpha channel?

Comment: If I save it without conversion it is fine. The output image is the same as the input


    `img = Image.open("input_image.png")`
    `img.save("output_image.png")`
 
If I convert to RGBa I get the following error message:
    `img = Image.open("input_image.png")`
    `img_rgba = img.convert("RGBa")`

  _File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/pisr3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1076, in convert_
    _im = im.convert(mode, dither)_
         _^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^_
_ValueError: conversion from L to RGBa not supported_

Answer (score 2):

Your original image is a 16-bit greyscale image. You can see that if you print the image:

```
im = Image.open(...)
print(im)
```

You'll see it is in I mode, i.e. 32-bit because that's what PIL uses for 16-bit images.

```
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=I size=502x1180>
```

You can also see that with `exiftool`, if you run:

```
exiftool YOURIMAGE
```

When you convert it to RGBA mode, PIL makes it into RGBA8888 - i.e. 4 channels of 8 bits each and you lose data.

---

If you want to convert from GREY16 to RGBA8888 with solid blacks and whites, you need to rescale to range 0..255 like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open 16-bit image and make Numpy array version
im = Image.open('image.png')
na = np.array(im)

# Rescale to range 0..255
res = (na - na.min())*255/(na.max()-na.min())

# Make back into uint8 PIL Image
pi = Image.fromarray(res.astype(np.uint8))

# Convert to RGBA8888
pi = pi.convert('RGBA')
pi.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Great analysis!  But there has to be an easy way to fix it?

Comment: @MarkRansom It depends why OP wants to make it RGBA and what he wants to do next with it. On the face of it, producing two further identical copies of the grey channel to make RGB does not add any new information , nor does adding a pointless alpha channel. There probably is a solution, but it's not currently clear why we need to do things that cause a problem.

Comment: The OP was pretty clear about what they're looking for; whether it's a good idea or not is not for us to judge.  They probably just want to combine it with another image that's already RGBA.

Comment: The only issue I see here, is figuring out, if the read image was actually 32-bit or 16-bit, to scale the value properly.

Comment: @gre_gor Mmm, not really. PNG cannot be 32-bit greyscale, only 16-bit max.

Comment: If the original image is 16-bit grayscale, OP's actual need may be the conversion to 8-bit. There're various environments that simply don't support 16-bit PNG. Not too long ago browsers did not support it either.

Answer (score 1):

PIL opening 16-bit grayscale PNG images as 32-bit, is [a known issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3796).

But that's not the only problem. Even first converting it to `I;16` mode (with `.convert("I;16")`, won't work, since PIL won't properly scale the grayscale values to RGB either way.

You can scale the values with the [`.point`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.point) method.
Assuming you will read images in other formats, you should do a check, if it needs this fix.

```
img = Image.open(input_image)
if (img.format == "PNG" and img.mode == "I") or img.mode == "I;16":
    img = img.point(lambda p: p * (1 / 256))
img_rgba = img.convert("RGBA")
img_rgba.save(output_image)
```